# How to remove selected GET value from a URL

Tags: php

I have this line of code:

```
echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

and this will return:

```
http://example.com?pageview=myview&edit=true&message=tester
```

my question is that how can I remove the `message=tester` from the `echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` ?

any idea please.. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to do this with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php), have you tried these?

Comment: Will what you want to remove from the end of the string *always* be `message=tester`?

Comment: as what @kittykittybangbang said.. is it always have to be `tester` is the value of `message`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is remove a known substring from the end of a string, you can use `rtrim()`.

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

> rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

`rtrim()` accepts 2 parameters, the second of which is optional. The first is the string, and the second, if present, is the substring to be removed from the end of the string.

So, in your case:

```
echo rtrim(str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'message=tester');
```

This will return:

```
http://example.com?pageview=myview&edit=true&
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general solution to remove any GET parameter, explode the whole URL by ? then get the parameters and lately locate the key you want to remove

```
$url = explode("?",str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$params = explode("&",$url[1]);
foreach ($params as $key=>$value) {
   if (strstr($value,"message=")===0) unset($params[$key]);
}
$url[1]=implode("&",$params);
echo implode("?",$url);
```

That's it. In case you want to delete the parameter if it has an specific value do something like:

```
if (strstr($value,"message=tester")===0) unset($params[$key]);
```